# Subsetting multi-dim. array with matrices

Tags: arrays, r, subset

i want to subset a 3-dimensional array with three matrices where each matrix represents one dimension.
An example:

```
    set.seed(1)
    A = array(sample(1:10,24, replace=TRUE), dim=c(3,4,2))

    ind_dimension1 = matrix(c(1,3,2,1), nrow=2)
    ind_dimension2 = matrix(c(4,3,2,1), nrow=2)
    ind_dimension3 = matrix(c(1,2,2,1), nrow=2)
```

As result i want a matrix with the same dimension as the subsetting matrices, i.e. 2x2:

```
    # A[1,4,1](=1)    A[2,2,2](=8)
    # A[3,3,2](=10)   A[1,1,1](=3)
```

In Matlab this can be done by:

```
    A(sub2ind(size(A), ind_dimension1, ind_dimension2, ind_dimension3))
```

With two dimensions, i.e. `A2=A[,,1]`, the Matlab command `sub2ind(size(A2), ind_dimension1, ind_dimension2)` can be replicated in R with `(ind_dimension2-1)*dim(A2)[2]+ind_dimension1` as mentioned by Hiebeler (2010) https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Hiebeler-matlabR.pdf (Page 5). This is not possible in higher dimensions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
myMat <- matrix(A[cbind(c(ind_dimension1), 
                        c(ind_dimension2),
                        c(ind_dimension3))],
                  dim(ind_dimension1))

myMat
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    8
[2,]   10    3
```

This uses matrix subsetting (see `help("[")`) to extract the desired elements. The dimension matrices are turned into vectors with `c`, and then recombined into a matrix with `cbind` that is used to extract from the array. The resulting vector is fed to `matrix` and the desired dimensions are produces with `dim`.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what i wanted. Overall, subsetting seems a lot easier in R in comparison to Matlab.